# plot gradient with three dimensions (coded as red, green & blue) in a ternary plot (ggtern)

Tags: r, data-visualization, ggplot2, gradient

I have the following data frame;

```
df <- data.frame(expand.grid(A = seq(0,1,0.1), B = seq(0,1,0.1), C = seq(0,1,0.1)))
df <- df[rowSums(df[,1:3]) == 1,]
df <- data.frame(df, value_A = 0.2 * df$A + -0.4 * df$B + 0 * df$C, value_B = 0.8 * df$A + 0.1 * df$B + 0.5 * df$C, value_C = 0 * df$A + 0.8 * df$B + 0 * df$C)
df[,c(4:6)] <- (df[,c(4:6)] + abs(apply(df[,c(4:6)],1,min))) / (apply(df[,c(4:6)],1,max) + abs(apply(df[,c(4:6)],1,min)))

df <- data.frame(df, color = rgb(red=df$value_A, green=df$value_B, blue=df$value_C))
```

In the data-frame, each row gives me a proportion of A's, B's and C's that sum up to one.
Further, for each A, B and C, I have a value.

From these three values I generate one RGB value that gives me an indication of the relative importance of A,B & C under different proportions of A, B and C's.

Now I would like to plot these RGB values as a surface in a ternary plot.

I can plot one "dimension" with the following code using the `ggtern` package in R;

```
library(ggtern)

ggtern(df, aes(A,B,C, value=value_A)) + 
theme_showarrows() + 
stat_interpolate_tern(geom="polygon",
                     formula=value~x+y,
                     n=20, method='lm',
                     breaks=seq(0,1, by=0.001),
                     aes(fill=..level..), expand=F
) +
scale_fill_gradient(low="red", high="green")
```

But instead of `value_A`, I actually want to use the RGB values directly.

However, I can not figure out, how, instead of `value=value_A` I can specify the color value for each point from which the surface is calculated directly.

Is this possible with `ggplot2` / `ggtern`?

Comment: This belongs on [SO], not here. We will migrate this for you.

Comment: Not sure if this will help or not, but you might be able to set the value to RBG color codes using functions like this?
https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grDevices/html/rgb.html

Comment: @ Bajcz; Yes, that is what I use to generate the RGB values .. however, plotting the surface does not take these RGB values directly, but expects a vector of values that is transformed into a color-gradient ... My problem is that I already have the color values and from these values want to create the surface.

Comment: You might need to take the approach of the heatmap, like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26221236/ternary-heatmap-in-r